# O(klogn) time algorithm to find kth smallest element from a Fenwick-Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, fenwick-tree

I mean to find the `kth` smallest actual frequency in a Fenwick-Tree in `O(k log(n))` time.
If my data is:

```
Tree = [1,3,1,10,3]
Actual frequency = [1,2,1,6,3]
```

So the second smallest element would be at index 1.

Comment: I don't understand the question and the example.

Comment: BIT = ? Is that some abbreviation?

Comment: Do you mean something like *O(Nlogk),* where *N* is the number of elements in the set?  (I agree with @KarolyHorvath:  I don't understand the question and the example.)

Comment: If the number of values is always small, this seems like an odd enough task to not bother with doing it the fast way.  Just do it the easy way.  Whatever the task is here.

Comment: @kol yes it stands for Binary Indexed Tree.

Comment: @MooingDuck the no of values can be large..

Comment: @MooingDuck its klogn

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? For frequencies [1,2,1,6,3] the tree should look like [1,3,1,10,3]. Or vice versa, for a tree [1,3,4,10,13] the frequencies should be [1,2,4,3,13]. I can easily be wrong, this is the first time I tried to calculate a BIT (pun intended).

Comment: @kol yes,it should have been [1,3,1,10,3] there .. earlier it was written Cumulative frequency there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well i thought of a possible solution,

```
while(start<=end){
   int mid=(start+end)>>1;
   if(read(mid)>=k)end=mid-1; // read(mid) returns the cummulative frequency.
   else start=mid+1;
}
```

start has to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need the kth smallest actual frequency, which I think cannot be determined without sorting the actual frequencies. If the only thing you have is the Fenwick tree, then you can calculate the sequence of actual frequencies in **O(n*log(n))** time (since you can calculate every single actual frequency in O(log(n)) (see [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees#reada)), and you have n frequencies). Sorting the sequence of actual frequencies by quicksort takes **O(n*log(n))**, and finding the kth element of the sorted sequence takes **O(n)** (there may be entries with the same actual frequency, so you cannot do this in O(1); but you can use linear search). **So the whole search can be done in O(n*log(n)).**

Hope this helps. I don't have any idea how this could be done in O(k*log(n)).